# Fixed div once page is scrolled is flickering

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to have an advertisement block/div that will be switched to a fixed position once you scroll down the page.

Here is a demo of what I am trying to do and the code I am using to do it with...

http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/6vpA7/3/embedded/result/

In the demo it works perfectly how I am wanting it to be, however when I implement it on my live site, http://goo.gl/zuaZx  it works but when you scroll down the div flickers in and out of view on each scroll or down key press.  On my site to see the problem live it is the block on the right sidebar that says "Recommended Books"

Here is the code I am using...

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(window).scroll( function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#social-container').offset().top)
            $('#social').addClass('floating');
        else
            $('#social').removeClass('floating');
    } );

} );​
```

css

```
#social.floating {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}​
```

My demo jsfiddle where it works correctly
http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/6vpA7/3/

The only thing different on my live site is the div/id name is different.  As you can see it is somewhat working on my live site except the flickering in and out of view as you scroll down the page.

Anyone have any ideas why this would happen on my live site and not on my jsfiddle demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice that in the example code, and your jsFiddle, your inner div (`#social`, `#text-2` etc) have a wrapper/container div which is where the `scrollTop()` test is performed. On your live code, you've ommited this wrapper, and you are both checking the `scrollTop()` AND setting the floating class on the same element (`#text-2`). So every time you scroll, it swaps between the classes, because the `scrollTop()` conditional keeps checking the same element. You need to wrap `#text-2` in another div and perform the conditional on that, just like in your examples.

Also, `#text-2` is an `li` element yet has no parent `ul`. You should either give it a parent `ul` or change it to a `div`, otherwise it's invalid HTML.